# Can not change default locale of moment.js in react component

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I want to change the dafault locale of this component to `fr`. Here is the component:

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';
import pt from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

moment.locale("fr");

class Ticker extends EventEmitter {
  tick = () => this.emit('tick');

  constructor(interval) {
    super();
    this.setMaxListeners(0);
    this.once('newListener', () => setInterval(this.tick, interval));
  }
}

const ticker = new Ticker(30000); // 30 sec

export default class TimeDisplay extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    timeStamp: pt.oneOfType([pt.number.isRequired, pt.string.isRequired]),
    className: pt.string,
    timeAgoInTitle: pt.bool,
  };

  refresh = () => this.forceUpdate();

  componentDidMount() {
    ticker.addListener('tick', this.refresh);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    ticker.removeListener('tick', this.refresh);
  }

  render() {
    moment.locale("fr");
    const time = moment(this.props.timeStamp);
    const timeAgo = Math.abs(moment().diff(time)) < 1000 ? 'maintenant' : time.fromNow();
    const timeISO = time.format();

    const title = this.props.timeAgoInTitle ? timeAgo : time.format('lll');
    const contents = this.props.children ? this.props.children : timeAgo;

    return (
      <time className={this.props.className} dateTime={timeISO} title={title}>{contents}</time>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see I've set `moment.locale("fr");` both after imports and at render but the moment strings are still shown in English. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `relativeTime` in `moment.locale`, Its better to use `moment.locale` in `componentWillMount` rather than `render` function

```js
moment.locale('fr', {
      relativeTime : {
          future : 'dans %s',
          past : 'il y a %s',
          s : 'quelques secondes',
          m : 'une minute',
          mm : '%d minutes',
          h : 'une heure',
          hh : '%d heures',
          d : 'un jour',
          dd : '%d jours',
          M : 'un mois',
          MM : '%d mois',
          y : 'un an',
          yy : '%d ans'
      }
  });
```

Comment: For some reason the snippet above does not work above, but it works on my react component. Thanks!